# typescript 2.0 node @typings

Tags: typescript, npm

I have been using the new @typings and when I do `npm install --save @types/react`, it creates a`@typings` folder in the `node_modules` folder and adds the dependency `@types/react: ^0.14.43` in the `package.json`.

When I clean node_modules and do a reinstall (npm i) it does not reinstall the @typings. Should it do this?

James

Comment: What version of npm are you using? Do you mean it doesn't install the *`@types`* folder?

Comment: Yes: _By default, npm install will install all modules listed as dependencies in package.json_

Comment: yes I meant @types

Answer (score 1):

> Should it do this?

Yes. To be clear the folder is called `@types` not `@typings`, perhaps that is confusing you. If not please installed latest node v6 (it comes with npm v3) since I just tested that.

Comment: @basarat how to use "@types" when im using in my project like this import * as express from "@types/express";
var app = express(); it throwing error can not find module @types/express

Comment: the problem was that I was not using npm v3